# How do I use the Google Maven replacer plugin to replace the string "${version}"?

Tags: maven, plugins, replace, maven-3

I’m using the 1.5.3 version of the Maven replacer plugin.  I want to replace the string “${version}” in my properties file, which contains the line

```
application.version=${version}
```

with the actual <version> element defined in my pom.  I’m trying this, but without success:

```
                <execution>
                    <id>replace-application-version</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <file>${project.build.outputDirectory}/application.properties</file>
                        <replacements>
                            <replacement>
                                <token>\${version}</token>
                                <value>${version}</value>
                            </replacement>
                        </replacements>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>replace</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
```

I don’t know how to properly escape the string “${version}” in the “<token>” block.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Better use the maven-resources-plugin and filtering which simpler.

Comment: If you can show how to control the phase of when the resources plugin runs, making everything else above the same, I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

For the Maven replacer plugin to look for the string “${version}” as a token without replacing it with the property value, you can specify the token as a regular expression by adding `<regex>true</regex>` and leave it like this:

```
<execution>
    <id>replace-application-version</id>
    <phase>compile</phase>
    <configuration>
        <file>${project.build.outputDirectory}/application.properties</file>
        <regex>true</regex>
        <replacements>
            <replacement>
                <token>\$\{version\}</token>
                <value>${version}</value>
            </replacement>
        </replacements>
    </configuration>
    <goals>
        <goal>replace</goal>
    </goals>
</execution>
```